# How do I get 3 selection options to work together?

Tags: html, dropdown

```html
<select>
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

> I would like to have three drop downs that will change depending on the selected option. Such as a vehicle type selector where you first choose a brand, then a model, and so forth. I was able to get two drop downs to work but not three of them. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do this but you have not said what you have attempted.

Comment: Why tagged with JAVA?

Answer (score -1):

It sound like a lot of fun with JS.
As i understood your target is that the form extends/canges it self by user actiones.
So you have to listen to the onChange on the select and use `DOM` to manipulate the form.

Comment: Its only one way